# Intuition relating OLS Variance-Covariance matrix and the OLS sampling variance equation

Tags: variance, least-squares

I'm looking at the variances of OLS slope estimators and I found the following equation that holds under the Gauss-Markov assumptions. Suppose that we have a multiple regression model of the following form:

$$
y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2} + ... + \beta_{k}x_{k} + u
$$

Estimating this equation via OLS, we can compute the variance of slope estimator $\hat{\beta}_j$ using the following equation:

$$
\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\beta}_{j}) = \frac {\sigma^{2}} {\mathrm{SST}_{j}(1 - R_{j}^{2})}
$$

From Wooldridge Appendix 3A, we can rewrite the denominator of this equation as:

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \hat{r}_{ij}^{2} = \mathrm{SST}_{j}(1 - R_{j}^{2})
$$

where $\hat{r}_{ij}$ is the residual from the regression of $x_{j}$ on all $x_{k \neq j}$. This is to say that $x_{ij} = \hat{x}_{ij} + \hat{r}_{ij}$ for all $i = 1, ... n$, where $\hat{x}_{ij}$ represents the fitted values and $\hat{r}_{ij}$ represents the residuals. This formula provides the variance for any individual $\hat{\beta}_{j}$. In addition, the matrix formulation for the variance of the slope estimator is as follows:

$$
\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\beta}|\pmb{X}) = \sigma^{2}(\pmb{X}'\pmb{X})^{-1}
$$

Looking at these two formulations, I am trying to understand the intuition for why the denominator of the first equation for different values of $j$ equals the diagonal values in the matrix expression in the second equation. In other words, why does diagonal of the matrix $(\pmb{X}'\pmb{X})^{-1}$ equal the sum of squared residuals of the regression of $x_{j}$ on $x_{k \neq j}$?

(citation: Wooldridge, Introductory Econometics, 7th edition)

Comment: Your final equation makes no sense, because $(X^\prime X)^{-1}$ is a $k\times k$ matrix while the left hand side is a number (presumably: you haven't defined $\hat r$).  Your citation to Wooldridge App 3A also cannot be correct, because the left hand side has nothing to do with the undefined subscript "$j$" on the right hand side of that equation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I edited the subscripts and tried to clarify that I meant the diagonals of $(\pmb{X}'\pmb{X})^{-1}$, not that the values were actually equal.